# Simple PHP signup script not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a signup script in PHP. It is being inserted into the database when it's submitted, however the inputted username, password and email are blank (there's no text in the database).

Here's my script;

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","dbuser","dbpass","dbname");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `users` (username, password, email) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email')");

}
?>

<form method="POST">
<input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username">
<input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
<input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtDHY.png)

Comment: I don't see why this would cause nothing to be passed in, but why are your vars in quotes? They are already strings.

Comment: Don't you think, your form should be above your Php code !

Comment: @amflare: Because string values need to be quoted.  Though that could be avoided entirely in this case by using prepared statements and query parameters.

Comment: @M.S.P: What difference would that make?

Comment: @M.S.P his form has no action, so it passes the results to the page its on.

Comment: @David I just gave it a try!

Comment: @David I use PDO when I do this, so I'm not familiar with this set up, but does the var not pass in the quotes on its own? It is a string after all.

Comment: @amflare: Because string values don't *contain* quotes.  String *literals* need quotes around them to denote them as being strings.  Otherwise the interpreter would have no way of knowing what's a string and what isn't.

Comment: @M.S.P: Awesome!  So now you also know that it makes no difference!

Comment: @David, and you earn one reputation over their!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if your problem comes directly from this, but when you use `mysqli_real_escape_string`, you have to send your connection as the first parameter of the function, see the doc for more details : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php . So this would look like this :

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
```

Probably that php tries to shoot some errors and exceptions, but by default, error logging is disabled with php. Try activating it with this at the top of your php file :

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow! That seems to of done the trick (adding `$con` as a parameter) - thank you, this was really bugging me.

Comment: Glad I could help :) When you use procedural style programming with SQL, you will almost all the time have to pass your connection as a prameter of the function, don't forget it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging your query:

```
echo "<pre>";

print_r($_POST); // Are username, email, password showing correctly in the array?

mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `users` (username, password, email) VALUES ('".$username."', '".$password."', '".$email"')") or die(mysqli_error($con)); // Will show an error if something'g wrong with the SQL syntax
```

Check your mysqli_real_escape_string syntax:

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);

$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);

$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD

Comment: Hmm... no error appears and the username, email and password are correct in the array

Comment: @questershelp var_dump your query and see what you get.

Comment: Looks like you need to use correct syntax for mysql_real_escape_string. Please view my edited post.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add action attribute to the form, like that :

```
<form method="POST" action="yourfilename.php" id="join">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
```

Comment: Not if it posts to the same page